# How to print the last but one record of a file using sed?

Tags: unix, sed

I want to print the last but one record of a file using sed.

```
sed -n '$p' filedata
```

This command used to get last record, but I want last but one record. I should do it without using head and tail commands.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you read the records in array and then use something like length -1 ?

Comment: well if head/tail is restricted for whatever reason, how about `tac+sed` ?

Comment: Lorem Ipsum
It has survived
professor 
The standard 
This is a dummy file
Sydney College
cites of the world
The chunk of data
It has survived  


This is the data in the file and i should return last but one record i.e 'The chunk of data'

Comment: How about `seq 100 | sed 'x;$!d'`

Comment: Thanks Mark Setchell.....It just fits for my requirement....

Comment: Sundeep  I have no idea about tac+sed...could you please explain command if possible......

Comment: @NaveenKumar see the duplicate question, it has all sorts of answers, including the tac+sed